# Why does Scala prefer implicit parameters over extending a trait?

Tags: java, scala, implicit-parameters

Scala ordering API uses implicit objects.
e.g.:

```
def msort[T](xs: List[T])(implicit ord: Ordering) = { ...}
```

Java uses Comparable interface for the same purpose.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) { ... }
```

Why does Scala prefer implicit types over extending a trait? What are the benefits of implicit parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use `msort` with multiple `Ordering`s for a given type. A type extending `Comparable` can only extend it in one way. (Some people consider this a disadvantage.)
2. You can provide an `Ordering` for a type which was implemented without knowledge about it (for example, any Java type!). You can't make an existing type extend `Comparable` if it doesn't yet.